# How can I reuse ILogger in several classes within c# Azure Function project?

Tags: c#, function, azure

Building a C# Azure Function v2 project using Visual Studio 2017.
I defined just one function, but during the HTTP triggered execution several  classes are instantiated. Most by my own code, some by JSON deserialization (so no control over how to call the constructor).

The function methods signature receives an ILogger instance that I use for logging.
What is the best way to let all my class instances make use of that same ILogger instance, without having to pass ILogger to every class instantiation?

I understand using a static var is not possible, since they are shared between different function invocations, while each invocation receives another ILogger instance.

Also, Dependency Injection seems not to be in place here, since the classes are used only internally, except for the JSON deserializable classes.

Following is my summarized code.
I could pass ILogger the the MyClass constructor, but myClass.PerformTheTask() performs complex code that uses and intantiates several classes, that all need to log stuff.

What is best way forward here?

```
[FunctionName("FunctionName")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "someroute{route}")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log,
        ExecutionContext context)
{
    var myClass = new myClass(); //how to make myClass and its children access ILogger?
    myClass.PerformTheTask();
}
```

Comment: Why is DI not the way to go? All classes you define, including the controllers, are "internal" to your own application - so if you really don't want to use DI, you should probably explain that reasoning a bit more. In my view, DI would be an as close to perfect fit as you're likely to find.

Comment: Well, maybe I don't have a correct understanding of DI, but the samples I found deal with a lot of extra code. And this is an Azure function, not .Net Core. I don't have controllers, nor a ServiceConfiguation class and my feeling is that I don't need them. It seems really overdone. Is there no other way?

Comment: If your `myClass` is dependent on `ILogger` you have to explicitly instantiate or pass via  constructor/method/property or let the DI framework do that for you.

Comment: Azure Functions V2 are .NET Core. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) and [here](https://medium.com/capax-brainpower/azure-functions-v2-dependency-injection-using-net-core-fccd93b80c0) for examples of using DI.

Answer (score 1):

@EricG,

As rightly said by Fredrik, You can use Dependency injection in Azure function V2 which is supported now.Azure Functions builds on top of the ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection features.

You can find the Azure samples here and in the git [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/tree/master/src/samples/DependencyInjection) for reference.

It's quite easy to use and more cleaner.It uses constructor injection for injecting the dependency.

```
public class SampleFunction
    {
        private readonly MyServiceA _serviceA;
        private readonly MyServiceB _serviceB;
        private readonly IGlobalIdProvider _globalIdProvider;

        public SampleFunction(MyServiceA serviceA, MyServiceB serviceB, IGlobalIdProvider globalIdProvider)
        {
            _serviceA = serviceA ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceA));
            _serviceB = serviceB ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceB));
            _globalIdProvider = globalIdProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(globalIdProvider));
        }

        [FunctionName("SampleFunction")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Service A ID: {_serviceA.IdProvider.Id}. Service B ID: {_serviceB.IdProvider.Id}");

            return new OkObjectResult(new
            {
                ProvidersMatch = ReferenceEquals(_serviceA.IdProvider, _serviceB.IdProvider),
                GlobalId = _globalIdProvider.Id,
                ServiceAId = _serviceA.IdProvider.Id,
                ServiceBId = _serviceB.IdProvider.Id
            });
        }
    }
```

Similarly you can do it with ILogger and use it in classes. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you.  I think I understand DI. What I just dont get' is how to make ILogger, which is injecedt by default, available to my own defined classes without passing ILogger around with every class-instantiation. Like in my OP, I create a myClass(). And MyClass creates a big object-tree. An example with an additional class, instantiated in the Run-body, that uses ILogger (or MyServiceA) would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to clarify what I aim for...a way to go would be to inherit all my classes from a BaseClass that contains a public property 'ILogger Logger', and instantiate them with 'new myClass() { Logger = this.Logger }. But that seems really dirty. In other scenarios I would use a static or singleton, but that's  not possible with Azure functions since they are shared between different function invocations.